# If $f(n) =\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{n}\Biggl(r^n\Bigg(\binom{n}{r}-\binom{n}{r-1}\Bigg) + (2r+1)\binom{n}{r}\Biggr)$, then what is $f(30)$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Please give me hints on how to solve it.
I tried 2-3 methods but it doesn't go beyond two steps. I am out of ideas now.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean $f(n) = \sum_{r=1}^{n}((r^n)(\dbinom{n}{r}-\dbinom{n}{r-1}) + (2r+1)\dbinom{n}{r})$, instead of $f(x)$?

Comment: f(x) doesn't depend on $x$...

Comment: @Arthur yes. typing mistake

Answer (score 3):

We may simply deal with each piece separately:
$$ \sum_{r=1}^{n}(2r+1)\binom{n}{r}=\left.\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n}{r}x^{2r+1}\right|_{x=1}=\left.\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\cdot\left(1+x^2\right)^n-1\right)\right|_{x=1}=2^n(n+1)-1.$$
On the other hand, by summation by parts:
$$ T_n=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{r}-\binom{n}{r-1}\right)r^n \\= n^n\left(\binom{n}{n}-\binom{n}{0}\right)-\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\left(\binom{n}{r}-1\right)((r+1)^n-r^n) $$
so:
$$ T_n = n^n-1-\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{r}((r+1)^n-r^n) $$
and you may compute the last sum through [Dobinski's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: How did this step come?
 $T_n=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{r}-\binom{n}{r-1}\right)r^n$
$n^n\left(\binom{n}{n}-\binom{n}{0}\right)-\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\left(\binom{n}{r}-1\right)((r+1)^n-r^n)$